# how to determine which method to use based on set size

Tags: java

I have an arraylist that stores Nodes (Points with references to surrounding nodes). this is in 2D space (Nodes are  currently just points) so the arrayList is a 1D representation of all my Nodes whereas the links in each node can link to surrounding Nodes (not just previous and next).

when searching through the ArrayList for the point that is closest to my mouse I have two options. either a for loop through the arraylist with a distance condition, or alternatively query a node, and determine the next linked node based on the direction of my mouse from the current node.

my thinking is that the for loop would be more efficient for smaller sets of nodes since the extra calculation to determine the next node is not necessary whereas querying the node would make more sense in large sets.

My question is how do I test at what point it becomes more efficient to do the calculation rather than just a for loop?

PS. if this is the wrong place to ask this question, I would appreciate a suggestion of somewhere that would be more appropriate to ask

Comment: if the points are randomly allocated within your 1D array then it makes sense to stop looping over array if the distance between mouse and array element goes below some specific threshold, after that you may analyze the nodes around it. that threshold should be chosen carefully though since if improperly chosen you will end up doing unnecessary iterations and in the worst case you will scan the whole array

Comment: That's what i was thinking but how do i determine the threshold

Comment: by analyzing some amount of test data